# Is there a linear embedding of a simplical 3-complex in R^6?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, simplicial-stuff

I've heard that there always is an embedding in $R^7$ (can someone provide a reference for that?) and this number cannot be lowered in general. But I'm interested in a somewhat special case, namely: complexes that are small deformations of complexes embeddable in $R^3$. In other words - start with a simplical complex in $R^3$ and change the dimensions of some of the cells. The resulting complex in general cannot be embedded in $R^3$ any more and $R^7$ always suffices. Is $R^6$ enough in this case?

Comment: ${\bf R}^7$ is presumably a special case of the embedding of any finite $n$-complex in $2n+1$ dimensional space: first embed in a space of really high dimension by sending each vertex to a different basis vector; then project to a random ${\bf R}^{2n+1}$.  This works because generically $n$-dimensional subspaces of $2n+1$ dimensional space don't meet.

[And you might want to correct the typo in the title: missing the last I in "simplicIal".]

Comment: What do you mean by "change the dimensions of some of the cells" ?

Comment: @BS: I assume he means to change the sizes of the cells.

Answer (score 3):

There's an obstruction to embedding $n$-complexes in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ provided $n \geq 3$ due to Shapiro.

MR0089410 (19,671a)
Shapiro, Arnold
Obstructions to the imbedding of a complex in a euclidean space. I. The first obstruction.
Ann. of Math. (2) 66 (1957), 256–269.

or as Ian suggests, van Kampen pre-dates Shapiro.

JFM 58.0615.03 van Kampen, E. R.
Berichtung zu:``Komplexe in euklidischen Räumen''. (German)
Abhandlungen Hamburg 9, 152-153 (1932).

Could you be more precise on how you want to modify the your complexes that originally are in $\mathbb R^3$, your special case?

Comment: Many people call this Van Kampen's embedding obstruction: 
http://www.springerlink.com/content/m71886j8mu666061/